# ID3D11VideoDevice::CreateVideoDecoderOutputView fails

Tags: directx, h.264, directx-11, hardware-acceleration, dxva

I'm developing an application able to decode H264 stream through DrectX11's ID3D11VideoDecoder interface ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447766(v=vs.85).aspx ) and I got stuck at ID3D11VideoDevice::CreateVideoDecoderOutputView method, it just fails returning E_INVALIDARG. Yes, I know, there can be millions of reasons, 
but are there some exceptionally common maybe? Are there any samples available illustrating decoding through ID3D11VideoDecoder (I haven't found any) ? 
The part of my  code that I think is most likely to fail looks as follows:

```
// texture
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descT = { 0 };
descT.Width = 1024;
descT.Height = 768;
descT.MipLevels = 1;
descT.ArraySize =  1;
descT.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_NV12;
descT.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
descT.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descT.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DECODER; 
ID3D11Texture2D *pTex = nullptr;
pDX11VideoDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, 0, &pTex);

// decoder
D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_OUTPUT_VIEW_DESC desc;
desc.DecodeProfile = D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_H264_VLD_NOFGT; // what is     interesting it fails whatever decoder I choose
desc.Texture2D.ArraySlice = 1;
desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_VDOV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

HRESULT hr = pDX11VideoDevice->CreateVideoDecoderOutputView(pTex, &desc, &pVideoDecoderOutputView); // and here the fail occurs
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved the problem, there should be

```
desc.Texture2D.ArraySlice = 0;
```

in the snippet in post above. Still lots of work ahead